# Application.LoadLevel() with delay in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any possibility to delay loading the level after my character dies in game? I am using following code:

```
void Update () {
if (health.currentVal <= 0)
    Die ();
}
void Die(){
   Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

This basically respawn my scene but I would like to add sound and delay if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Invoke and wait for 5 seconds.

```
Invoke("Die",5);
```

You can also use coroutine

```
IEnumerator waitRestart()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); //Wait for 5 secs
    Die();
}
```

then call it with `StartCoroutine(waitRestart());`.

Comment: Great, works fine. Is it also possible to freeze or disable movement of "player" object while we wait until we restart game ? 

The new problem is that I am still able to move player while he is "dead".

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla yes. Create a boolean varaible and use it to determine when player is dead. For example, `bool isDead;` then in your move code make sure that player is not dead before moving the player. You can check that with `if(!isDead){//Put your move code here};`. The "!" means not dead. Also, before you call `Invoke("Die",5);`, make `isDead` is to be `true` when the player dies by doing `isDead = true;`. If you still have question about this, create new question since this is totally a different issue. Don't forget to accept this answer since you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Call with `Invoke()`. Second parameter is the time delay in seconds.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (health.currentVal <= 0)
    {
        Invoke("Die", 3f);
    }      
}
```